# TypeError testing Backbone.js in CoffeeScript with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm currently working through the [PeepCode video on Backbone.js](http://peepcode.com/products/backbone-js) but attempting to write it all in CoffeeScript rather than bare JavaScript.

So far so good, except when I try to run Jasmine tests on the code I run into some TypeErrors:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'isFirstTrack' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

My CoffeeScript/Backbone file looks like this:

```
jQuery ->
  class window.Album extends Backbone.Model
    isFirstTrack: (index) ->
    index is 0

  class window.AlbumView extends Backbone.View
    tagName:    'li'
    className:  'album'

    initialize: ->
      @model.bind('change', @render)
      @template = _.template $('#album-template').html()     
    render: =>
      renderedContent = @template @model.toJSON()
      $(@el).html(renderedContent)
      return this
```

And the Jasmine test spec like this:

```
var albumData = [{
  "title":  "Album A",
  "artist": "Artist A",
  "tracks": [
    {
        "title": "Track A",
        "url": "/music/Album A Track A.mp3"
    },
    {
        "title": "Track B",
        "url": "/music/Album A Track B.mp3"
    }]
}, {
  "title": "Album B",
  "artist": "Artist B",
  "tracks": [
    {
        "title": "Track A",
        "url": "/music/Album B Track A.mp3"
    },
    {
        "title": "Track B",
        "url": "/music/Album B Track B.mp3"
  }]
}];

describe("Album", function () {

  beforeEach(function () {
    album = new Album(albumData[0]);
  });

  it("creates from data", function () {
    expect(this.album.get('tracks').length).toEqual(2);
  });

  describe("first track", function() {
    it("identifies correct first track", function() {
      expect(this.album.isFirstTrack(0)).toBeTruthy();
    })
  });

});
```

I'm guessing the problem has something to do with CoffeeScript wrapping everything in a function. When I remove jQuery from the equation it works fine.
Strangely though even though Jasmine is telling me `TypeError: Cannot call method 'isFirstTrack' of undefined` if I run `album.isFirstTrack(0)` in the console on the page it returns `true` so the window does have access to the variables and methods.

Comment: After digging around some more - I've managed to fix it. Removing the `this` keyword from the two `expect` statements in the Jasmine test spec seems to work. Would still be interested to understand why though - is this a scope issue?

Comment: The problem isn't CoffeeScript's function wrapper. You've correctly exported your two classes by defining them as `window.Album` and `window.AlbumView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is scoping, yes.

when you declare the `album` variable with no `var` keyword and without attaching it to another object, you are creating a variable in the global scope.

this is a bad idea. you really want to limit the number of global objects that you create, because it's easy for another chunk of javascript to overwrite your data, or cause conflicts, etc.

your idea of calling `this.model` in the tests is correct from this perspective. the problem is that you need to attach `model` to `this` to be able to do that. easy enough:

```
  beforeEach(function () {
    this.album = new Album(albumData[0]);
  });
```

all you have to do is say `this.album = ...` and you're done. now your tests will be able to find `this.album` and everything should work.

Comment: Right, `album =` and `this.album =` are not equivalent (unless `this` is `window`, which isn't the case when Jasmine calls the `beforeEach` callback).

Answer (score 2):

(**Note**: I believe Derick's answer is correct—it explains the `TypeError: Cannot call method 'isFirstTrack' of undefined` message—but this answer may also be pertinent.)

You say

> When I remove jQuery from the equation it works fine.

Meaning that if you cut out the line `jQuery ->`, then your tests pass? If that's the case, it's not a scope issue; it's a code order issue. When you pass a function to jQuery, that function isn't executed until the document is ready. Meanwhile, your tests are running immediately—before the `Album` and `AlbumView` classes are defined.

There's no reason to use the `jQuery ->` wrapper, since your class definitions don't depend on any existing DOM elements.

Comment: Great answer and a very good suggestion. Unless something needs to run when jQuery is ready jQuery -> simply isn't necessary.